# Disable Validation When TextBox Empty

Tags: c#

I have a form with several text boxes for entering dates. I am using text boxes, because some of the dates can be null. datePickers and maskedTextBoxes require a value. I am using the code below to validate the dates.  The text boxes are correctly accepting no entry, a date with the format of "MMddyyyy" My problem is when the user enters a date, and then "Oops! That's in the wrong spot!" The user cannot delete the date, and exit the text box. Is there a way to cancel validation when the value of the text box is null or empty?

```
    private void TextBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox S1 = (TextBox)sender;
        bool rVal = Tools.ValidDate(S1);
        e.Cancel = (rVal) ? false : true;
    }


public static string[] formats = { "M/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "Mdyyyy", "MMddyyyy" };

        public static bool ValidDate(TextBox S1)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(S1.Text)) { return true; }

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(S1.Text, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime D1))
        { S1.Text = D1.ToShortDateString(); return true; }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("Invalid date format"); return false; }

    }
```

UPDATE:
I found a different solution for a different validation problem.

"In order to fix the validation failure, which is due to the inability of the databinding to set DBNull.Value into the textbox.text, you may add the following line in the Form_Load section:"

```
TextBox1.DataBindings["Text"].NullValue = string.Empty;
```

So, I changed the ValidateDate function as follows:

```
        public static bool ValidDate(TextBox S1)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(S1.Text)) { S1.DataBindings["Text"].NullValue = string.Empty; return true; }

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(S1.Text, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime D1))
        { S1.Text = D1.ToShortDateString(); return true; }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("Invalid date format"); return false; }
    }
```

Comment: "datePickers and maskedTextBoxes require a value" - why do you believe this? Plenty of things are nullable dates.

Comment: This is not getting stuck when null or empty, you have handled it.

Answer (score 0):

This will help.
private void TextBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
bool rVal;
TextBox S1 = (TextBox)sender;
if(!string.isnullorempty(S1.text))
{
rVal= Tools.ValidDate(S1);
}
e.Cancel = (rVal) ? false : true;
}